# Ubuntu installer crashes with grub-install /dev/sda failed fatal error

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04.1 in a machine for dual boot with Windows 7, via a bootable flash drive. I've made the memory partitions for swap, esp, home etc. But, the installation failed for some reason the first time. And every time I try to install overwriting the earlier choosing the option `Erase Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and reinstall`, the installation crashes towards the end with `Executing 'grub-install /dev/sda' failed. This is a fatal error.`

This is the last [message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JziV.jpg) before it fails :

```
ubuntu grub-installer: Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is not owned by us (uid 0), but by uid 999!(This could eg happen if you try to connect to a non-root PulseAudio as a root user, over the native protocol. Don't do that.) 
error: failed to register the EFI boot entry: Operation not permitted.
```

I have made the partition for EFI and labelled it boot, this is in the partition `dev/sda6`

[Gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EA1zq.jpg)
This is the partitions created.

Now with that partial(?) installation, in the UEFI Boot menu, there is an option for Ubuntu. But on selection, it just says, `no boot device found, press any key to reboot the machine`; probably because of incomplete installation.

Unsure what to do from here, any help would be appreciated for a working installation of Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you manually create the **/target** reference? Your efi directory would normally be **/boot/efi** and your root directory just **/** and in 20.04 you don't need a swap directory as it uses a swap file in your / directory.

Comment: @darth_epoxy yes I manually created the / references when I first tried to make the installations. I shrunk some memory, then made these 4 new partitions (sda5, 6, 7, 8) if thats what you are asking. But I don't know how **/target..** ended up being there in the _mount point_.

Comment: You have MBR(msdos) partitions and then Windows has to be BIOS boot. You cannot have both Windows BIOS boot and UEFI boot on same drive. Windows requires boot flag on its bootable NTFS partition, often sda1 and UEFI requires boot/esp flags on ESP partition. And only one boot flag per drive. How you boot install media is how it installs. But since UEFI system, better to retire Windows 7 and install only in UEFI boot mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oldfred answered this 90% in a comment but I feel the ultimate advice was incorrect.

If you opt for EFI boot, you **must** use [GPT partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) rather than [MBR partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record).  It appears that your previous Win7 install was installed in MBR mode rather than EFI so now you're stuck with MBR as long as you want Win7 still on there.

The easiest solution here is to boot your install media not using EFI as Ubuntu is perfectly happy running with MBR partitions.  I don't know how you made your boot media but typically there are options to explicitly make it MBR only.  Failing that, the BIOS boot menu should clearly state whether you're booting USB in EFI (or not) mode.

Comment: I ended up totally formatting the hard drive and removed Windows 7 as it is deprecated anyway. My boot menu is already messed up.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error trying to install Ubuntu 21.1 coexiting with Windows 10.

Went into Windows 10, opened Disk Management and deleted the physical partition where Ubuntu installation was attempted, which also deleted the logical partitions that Unbuntu installation had created.

Tried to run the installation again and it worked fine, finished without errors.

Comment: 22.04 + windows11. This worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using new UEFI BIOS, at the `Device for boot loader installation`, you must create an EFI (ESP) type partition and select it (e.g. 1024M size `/dev/sda1`, (do not select `/dev/sda`).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, later on I realized that I was supposed to have the EFI partition as the first partition on my disk, just check if this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is 13 years old but I spent my whole day yesterday trying to install ubuntu on a toshiba satellite Nb10t and would always have the fatal error and even with boot repair, set root on grub nothing would work. I finally fixed it:

### I installed windows.

how funny if I just ended this here xD

so inside windows I downloaded and installed an updated BIOS who would allow me a few more choices I couldn't before.

After I burn the xubuntu iso (I guess any ubuntu would do) on a flash drive with GPT partitioning.

after I turn the pc on, put it on Legacy mode (no uefi options, all out the window)

and it installed beautifully, no errors and no problems booting it up.

I few years back I had the same problem and that's how I solved it but I compleatly forgot and since the previous bios didn't have that option it never came to mind.

Hope it helps anyone who lens here or myself in a few years xD

Answer (score 0):

Keps I believe I had a similar issue to what you had. I have a gigabyte brix gb-bxbt-2807 and in the bios it was setup up to windows 8.1. I kept getting the "/dev/sda failed fatal error" and I tried the installation several times. After reading your comment I went into my bios to find a legacy setting, but there was nothing there. I then noticed the OS setting in one of the pages. I decided to change it from windows 8.1 to windows 7 and the next time I did the ubuntu 22.04 install it worked.