# Many failures trying to re-install ubuntu

Tags: boot, reinstall

My situation has just gone from bad to worse.  First I had an issue that suddenly started with a black screen with just a cursor.  I spent a couple of days trying to fix it.  Now I've decided to reinstall (I do have my files backed up).

So, I begin the reinstall, and it failed with a 'executing grub-install failed this is a fatal error".

OK.  So then I tried again, and now I'm getting a ubi-partman failed with exit code 10.  Basically I can quit - which leaves me with a brick.  Or I can continue... which will likely leave me with a brick.

I have 2 500GB SSD's.  One has 1 partition, and I use it for media files.  It is not my boot drive.  However, for this discussion, it is important to note that device is '/dev/nvme0n1', an ext4 v1 linux file system.

The other drive is where I *had* Ubuntu 20.04.03 previously installed.  It is '/dev/nvme1n1' with 3 partitions.  The first partition, '/dev/nvme1n1p1' is 768MB, is and EFI system FAT (32).  It is where the old boot was.

The 2nd partition is and empty 539MB of free space (why I don't know).  It is called '/dev/nvme1n1'.

The 3rd partition is where all the linux files were, is is 511GB, and is '/dev/nvme1n1p4'.  It is saying it is a linux ext4 v1.

When the first grub failure occurred, it said it could not install on '/dev/nvme01n1'.  So it gives me a choice to go to others, all of which show the same failure.

What do I do now?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you trying to install? If it's 21.10, are you using ZFS? 

Comment: Sorry 20.04.03 LTS.  What is ZFS?

Comment: If you're not sure what ZFS is, then you're not using it. No worries. [Does this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1275716/1222991) help?

Comment: See my additional notes I just added above.  No, that won't work.  I'm on a pure metal Linux.  No Windows has ever been on it.  The drive/partition/fs info is above,

Comment: Ubuntu's Ubiquity installer only installs grub to first drives ESP - efi system partition. It looks like your ESP is on second drive. Did you change drive order? You just needed to reinstall grub either with Boot-Repair or manually using external flash drive.  Some work arounds in this still active very old bug. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379